# Selecting from the result set of a DB2 stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a stored procedure which returns multiple records (the SP cannot be changed, I need to work with what I have). I'd like to do a DB2 select statement from Shell script that selects one record based on a combination of column data like the following:

```
select a.description_column from (call my_stored_proc) a where a.name_column='name_filter' and a.value_column='value_filter';
```

The columns `description_column`, `name_column` and `value_column` exist in the result set of the SP. I get a `SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2` error. As I need to sort it out from a Shell script and I only have read access to the DB, I can't create additional tables for this.

Comment: Which platform/version of DB2, please?  Also, do you know how the stored proc is returning rows?  That is, how is the stored proc declared?  The listed error is DB2's way of saying 'look deeper' - is there more to the message?

Comment: You cannot "select" from a result set returned by a stored procedure. You'd need to write some SQL PL code (e.g. an anonymous block) to process it, as described [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009166.html)

Comment: I ended up composing a query based on the source of the SP. Now it does what I need it to do. Nevertheless I still think it would be cool if DBMSs could process such queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select from SP.

But you can from a Table-Function.

```
SELECT ... FROM TABLE(<table-function(param1, param2, ..., paramN))) as t WHERE ....
```

So, easiest way is to ask the DBA to create a table-function based in the source SP.

Good luck